# Kernel Density Estimation on Path Space

Tags: kernel-smoothing

I'm trying to reproduce some results from a paper (http://www.alexwg.org/publications/PhysRevLett_110-168702.pdf for reference) where you are basically trying to estimate a path integral. You have equations of motion for evolving individual paths and the method seems to be that you sample a number of paths in order to estimate the path probability density. This is from the supplementary information:

[image]

So $\vec{x_i}(t)$ is a path that is discretized into timesteps (in the example I'm doing 400 timesteps with an x-component and a y-component at each timestep). Now I don't know very much about kernel density estimation, but this strikes me as a difficult problem as the path space in my example is 800 dimensional, and unsurprisingly if I just feed it into MATLAB's mvksdensity function (to estimate just the path probability density) it just returns a lot of zeros. Is there something about the fact that you are trying to estimate not the actual probability density but $\log(\frac{\Omega_i}{\sum \Omega_{i'}})$ where $\Omega_i = \frac{1}{M p_i}$ (M is number of sample paths) that makes it easier? If so how do you go about doing this?